# google map api v3 - place marker at the bottom of the map div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am trying to create a location based search application. I need to display search results using marker. By using the Marker code sample from google map javascript API, the marker is displayed at the center of the map div. I need to point the marker at the bottom of the map so that i can show the search result above the marker.

Check this url http://www.groupon.com/now#/categories?address=denver&hint=47.5615%2C-52.7127&lat=39.7391536&lng=-104.9847034 . It shows marker to the bottom if the map. I need to disply like this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google map API has function to set the center point of view. If you don't provide it centers  the marker lat/long you provide. You need to add/subtract lat/long accordingly to set center position. From this I mean you should take the current lat/long of the marker in separate variables, add/subtract values to adjust centre point and set the map center point with those.
Hope this help. :)

Answer (score 2):

Placing the marker doesn't force the map to center on it - the map itself is being set so its centerpoint is the same as the marker. You need to set the center of the map to be 'above' (in latitude) the center of the marker. use `.setCenter(LatLng)` on the map object.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the reply from Oliver (thanks), here is what i did to solve this issue.
In https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference we see that we have to add    `map.setCenter({lat: -34, lng: 151});` - i have place it after this line     `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(your latitude, your longitude);`

To get the values i have opened the google map and i clicked on my area, the pointer shows at the bottom of the page and i see the latitude and longitude (we need them for the line `var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(your latitude, your longitude);` ).
Than i dragged the map down and clicked again in the middle of the map to see the latit. and longit. of that area and these two will be added in the line that you have to add -    `map.setCenter({lat: new latitude value, lng: new longitude value});`